# Rewrite doesn't work expectedly in NGINX

Tags: centos, php, nginx, rewrite

I'm using the following syntax for my rewrite in NGINX, and as far as I see it's working right! :

```
    location / {
         if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 break;
         }
    }
```

It's leading me through a login page written in PHP, but there are a problems occurring: It downloads the login page instead of showing it!

Does anybody know why it is happening? I'm using NGINX with php-fpm on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `break` to `last`. i.e. :

It should be:

```
rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1 last;
```

Instead of:

```
rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 break;
```